# How to persist ENUM string not ordinal value in hibernation dropwizard

Tags: hibernate, enums, dropwizard

I use dropwizard 0.8 with hibernate for database persistence. When persist enum column, it gets saved into database with its ordinal value, not the string value. I put `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` on top of the column model.

It makes me feel like dropwizard 0.8 doesn't honor EnumType.STRING at all.

Any help on this?

```
public enum State {
    NOTSTARTED,
    RUNNING,
    COMPLETE,
    ABORTING,
    ABORTED,
    FAILED;
}

public class Status implements Serializable{
    @Column(name="state")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private State state;

    @Column(name="error")
    private String error;

    Status() {
    }

    Status(State state, String error) {
        this.state = state;
        this.error = error;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Dropwizard v0.7.1 and MySQL v5.5.

The `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` annotation on two of column-mapped fields is working as expected (one field is mapped to a VARCHAR field and other to an ENUM)

Try the following:

- Downgrade Dropwizard to v0.7.1
- Make your `State` class a sub-class of `Status`

Comment: Thank you, I haven't tried to downgrade dropwizard to v0.7.x yet since my project has several places tied to 0.8.0 already due to itself dependency upgrades. I've solved the problem as what I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the problem by moving @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) from the field level to property level and it works.
I think it's because of the way I use Status class which is embedded in another class and annotated with Property access type. So in the status class, I should put the annotation on the property level as well.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job")
@JsonSerialize(include= JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class Job implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Embedded
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Status status;

    ...
}
```